# Transfer data to "Choose activity" when I press back button

Tags: android, transition, transfer

Now I run new Intent and transfer data to "PlayTravelledRouteActivity" through button in "MainActivity" like in this graph:

[image: CLICK]

But I want run new Intent from "Choose Activity" so I think that I should previously transfer data to "Choose Activity" and next to "PlayTravelledRouteActivity", but to get to "Choose Activity" from "MainActivity" I need click (smartphone) back button like in this graph:

[image: CLICK]

And ofc I know where insert code for transfer data from "Choose Activity" to "PlayTravelledRouteActivity" (in button "Play" onClickListener), but **I don't know where I should insert this code:**

```
/** lat_GPS,lon_GPS,roll_angle,pitch_angle -> double[] = new double[600], licznik -> int **/
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ChooseActivity.class);
intent1.putExtra("lat",lat_GPS);
intent1.putExtra("lon",lon_GPS);
intent1.putExtra("last_index",licznik);
intent1.putExtra("roll_angle",roll_Kalman_Filter);
intent1.putExtra("pitch_angle",pitch_Kalman_Filter);
startActivity(intent1);
```

to transfer data to "Choose Activity" from "MainActivity" ? Could someone tell me?

Comment: add it onbackpress() event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question you can use [**`onBackPressed()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())

> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back
>   key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity,
>   but you can override this to do whatever you want.

```
@Override
   public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        //super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ChooseActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("lat",lat_GPS);
        intent1.putExtra("lon",lon_GPS);
        intent1.putExtra("last_index",licznik);
        intent1.putExtra("roll_angle",roll_Kalman_Filter);
        intent1.putExtra("pitch_angle",pitch_Kalman_Filter);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
```

Comment: and insert this code for transfer data in this function?